# Python flask unittest gives AttributeError: type object 'Main' has no attribute 'app_context'

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have made a script that gives a JSON using Python Flask.

The URL for the JSON is `localhost:3000` and I can also get all days, day by ID or day by month and day.

- All days: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today/all`
- Today by ID: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today?id=2`
- Today by month and day: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today?month=05&day=05`

I want to create unit tests for the script. However my unittest gives me an **error:**

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s\PycharmProjects\TodayPython\tests\test.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.ctx = Main.app_context()
AttributeError: type object 'Main' has no attribute 'app_context'


Ran 1 test in 0.009s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

**Main.py:**

```
import datetime
import flask
from flask import jsonify, request, app


class Main:
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)  # Creates the Flask application object
    app.config["DEBUG"] = True

    # Readme
    dt = datetime.datetime.today()
    print("All days: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today/all")
    print("Today by ID: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today?id=2")
    print("Today by month and day: http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/resources/today?month=" + '{:02d}'.format(
        dt.month) + "&day=" + '{:02d}'.format(dt.day))

    def __init__(self):

        # Test data for our catalog in the form of a list of dictionaries.
        # Jokes from here: https://www.rd.com/list/short-jokes/
        self.todays = [
            {'id': 0,
             'month': '05',
             'day': '04',
             'historic_event': '1670 – A royal charter granted the Hudsons Bay Company a monopoly in the fur trade in Ruperts Land (present-day Canada).',
             'joke': 'What’s the best thing about Switzerland? I don’t know, but the flag is a big plus.'},
            {'id': 1,
             'month': '05',
             'day': '05',
             'historic_event': '2010 – Mass protests in Greece erupt in response to austerity measures imposed by the government as a result of the Greek government-debt crisis.',
             'joke': 'I invented a new word! Plagiarism!'},
            {'id': 2,
             'month': '05',
             'day': '06',
             'historic_event': '2002– Founding of SpaceX.',
             'joke': 'Did you hear about the mathematician who’s afraid of negative numbers? He’ll stop at nothing to avoid them.'},
        ]

        @self.app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
        def __home():
            return self.home()

        @self.app.route('/api/v1/resources/today/all', methods=['GET'])
        def __api_all():
            return self.api_all()

        @self.app.route('/api/v1/resources/today', methods=['GET'])
        def __api_id():
            return self.api_id()

        self.app.run(host="localhost", port=3000, debug=True)

    @staticmethod
    def home():
        return '''<h1>Today</h1>
        <p>A prototype API for finding out what happened on this day</p>'''

    def api_all(self):
        return jsonify(self.todays)

    def api_id(self):

        # Create an empty list for our results
        results = []

        # Check if an ID was provided as part of the URL.
        # If ID is provided, assign it to a variable.
        # If no ID is provided, display an error in the browser.
        if 'id' in request.args:
            id = int(request.args['id'])

            # Loop through the data and match results that fit the requested ID.
            # IDs are unique, but other fields might return many results
            for today in self.todays:
                if today['id'] == id:
                    results.append(today)
        else:
            # Month and day search
            if 'month' in request.args and 'day' in request.args:
                month = str(request.args['month'])
                day = str(request.args['day'])

                for today in self.todays:
                    if today['month'] == month and today['day'] == day:
                        results.append(today)

                result_length = len(results)
                if result_length == 0:
                    return "Error: Not yet implemented or not found"
            else:
                return "Error: No id, month or day field provided. Please specify."



        # Use the jsonify function from Flask to convert our list of
        # Python dictionaries to the JSON format.
        return jsonify(results)


Main();
```

**tests/test.py:**

```
import unittest

from Main import Main


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.ctx = Main.app_context()
        self.ctx.push()
        self.client = Main.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ctx.pop()

    def test_home(self):
        response = self.client.get("/", data={"content": "hello world"})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual("POST method called", response.get_data(as_text=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why did you expect that the `Main` class should have a method `app_context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Main class doesn't have an attribute `app_context`. According to [pytest for flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/testing/#tests-that-depend-on-an-active-context) Flask object does have this attribute.

So you should do `Main.app.app_context()` instead of `Main.app_context()`